# ¿Para crear bases de datos SQL en phpMyAdmin que admitan tildes ñ y demas.. que cotejamiento se debe usar?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hay alguna norma o estándar actualmente que especifique cual es la correcta para paginas con estos caracteres? en realidad no entiendo muy bien aun para que sirve el cotejamiento si es que así se dice.. hasta que nivel afecta esta configuración? es solo con la compatibilidad de lo escrito en la base de datos o pasa a los campos tambien? es decir que si no es compatible con ñ cuando el usuario inserte su nombre  de eejmplo ñoño no se lo reconocerá? Gracias por su ayuda :D

Answer (score 1):

Yo siempre utilizo utf8_spanish_ci ya que permite las ñ y además tiene codificación utf8

diferencias entre utf8_spanish_ci y utf8_spanish2_ci
http://mysql-manunuwi.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/utf8spanishci-vs-utf8spanish2ci.html

¿Por que utf8? -> http://www.tufuncion.com/utf8

PD, nunca utilices la ñ en nombre de tablas, columnas, etc..luego dan muchos problemas

Comment: Oh Muchas gracias por la información amigo! y en el caso de que no me interese la internacionalizacion como dice el segundo link... cual seria la recomendada? se que tambien estan los latin_spanish pero no se que diferencia tiene con esos :) Gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: @HeckDan la cosa está en que usar una codificación reducida como ISO-8859-1 (el famoso latin1) en persistencia puede traer muchos líos al mostrar la información en cualquier interfaz. Muchas configuraciones de plataformas, frameworks y entornos viene con UTF8 por defecto y te van a salir todos los líos que requieren decoding/encoding... y con no usar UTF8 no te estas ahorrando una enormidad en almacenamiento, así que tampoco es una ventaja.